# Regular Grammar to Language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I have a doubt about this grammar and which language generates, the Regular Grammar is:

$S → AB$
$AB → ABB$
$AB → AAB$

$B → b$

$A → a$

I guessed it only generates two languages.This one {ababbb} and {abaaba}, what do you think.

Comment: There is no $G$ defined above. I suppose $S$ is the "start". Note that it is not possible to exchange the places of $A,B$. Every word in $L=\{\ a^nb^m\ :\ n,m\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 1}\ \}$ can be generated. Conversely...

Comment: I thought $S$ generate $AB$ then $AB$ generates $ABB$ so the result we have until now is $ABABB$ and then adds a $B$ and  $A$ which convert letters to 'b' and 'a' so we have those languages, am I thinking wrong? How should I think it?

Comment: When you say "$AB$ generates $ABB$", that's a conversion, just like when $A$ becomes $a$, or when $S$ becomes $AB$. It is not a concatenation.

Comment: Oh, thanks @Arthur so it concatenates $ABAAB$ and then convert to letters? Is that 'well expressed' ?

Comment: A grammar generates **one** language. The language is a set of words. The words have letters $a,b$. To generate e.g. $a^3b^2$ one can use $$S\to \color{red}{AB}\to A\color{red}{AB}\to AA\color{red}{AB}\to AAABB\to\dots\to aaabb\ .$$ In the explicit cases when we use $\color{red}{AB}\to$ either $AAB$ or $ABB$ we still obtain words of the shape $[A,a]^+[B,b]^+$. How do you get that $ababbb$ from the question?

Comment: That's right I expressed the sentence in a bad way, regarding ababbb is wrong since the first b can't go in that position, I already understand how it concatenates the letters, thank you @dan_fulea.

Comment: As long as you keep saying "concatenate" I am concerned that you do not understand. These operations never **concatenate** strings, they **replace substrings**.